# FireFox Android phone full screen top statusbar issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox

I have written this webview app mainly using javascript, all seem fined
with Opera, google , only Firefox for phone only having this issue
when and after the key input in full screen. the top statusbar can't go away
even Firefox didn't return itself back to full screen.
when key input pic 1)

[image]

but work perfect on Opera, google, and browser in iphone..
no problem in Opera 1) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaXiE.png)

any help will be appreciated n thanks.

Comment: It is recommended to set the WebView layout height to a fixed value or to MATCH_PARENT instead of using WRAP_CONTENT. When using MATCH_PARENT for the height none of the WebView's parents should use a WRAP_CONTENT layout height since that could result in incorrect sizing of the views. See This article https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

After keyboard hided :

[image]

Firefox version :

Opera after keyboard hided back to full screen with no `statusbar`

[image]